# Did Harry Potter buy a new wand after the war?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In the **film** 'Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows II' we don't see Harry buy himself a new wand after the war, nor do we see him using the Elder Wand to repair his old wand (as he did in the novel).

What, if anything happened with Draco's wand? Did Harry continue to use Draco's wand from then on?

Comment: I guess this could become on-topic if you were interested in what he did for a wand, exclusively in the film universe. Even then it's pretty much answered by the dupe.

Comment: I feel like this should be in movies & tv '-'

Answer (score 8):

In the books Harry uses the Elder Wand to repair his own.

> He rummaged in the pouch hung around his neck, and pulled out the two
> halves of holly still just connected by the finest thread of phoenix
> feather. Hermione had said that they could not be repaired, that the
> damage was too severe. All he knew was that if this did not work,
> nothing would.
>
> He laid the broken wand upon the headmaster’s desk,
> touch it with the very tip of the Elder Wand, and said “Reparo.”
>
> As his wand resealed, red sparks flew out of its end. Harry knew that
> he had succeeded. He picked up the holly and phoenix wand and felt a
> sudden warmth in his fingers, as though wand and hand were rejoicing
> at their reunion. “I’m putting the Elder Wand,” he told Dumbledore,
> who was watching him with enormous affection and admiration, “back where it came from. It
> can stay there. If I die a natural death like Ignotus, its power will
> be broken, won’t it? The previous master will never have been
> defeated. That’ll be the end of it.”

Comment: I never understood why this was missed from the films: it seems so important that Harry chooses to retain his own wand (the one linked to Voldemort and his parent's death) rather than the one that could make him much stronger. It's a powerful statement about the character.

Comment: @JonStory While I disagree with the movie's change here (as I do with many other changes), Harry did make a similar choice there as well, by breaking the Elder Wand.

Comment: Although you're not wrong, this doesn't actually answer the question asked, e.g. What does he do **in the film**?

Comment: @Richard To be fair, the original question didn't indicate that. This answer was posted prior to the edit that changed all that.

Comment: They never show anything in the film.. This answer supplements the film. I feel the film-only HP fans should get answers from the books, as there is just a *lot* of stuff skipped in the movies...

Comment: I would suggest that in the film world, maybe Harry had already repaired his wand and we weren't shown it? If not, he probably kept Draco's wand as he had earned it and had its allegiance. Also he'd completed his quest against Voldemort wielding that wand so was probably becoming pretty attached to it. Draco can afford a new one!

Comment: I was absolutely sure I remembered this scene from the film. Was this ever part of the film? Or am I just imagining things?